# Generically Render Partial View - Convert PropertyInfo into Concrete Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am currently making a wizard in MVC (c#). But I have an if statement in my Wizard view that goes like this:

```
if (Model.Wizard.ClientDetails.GetStep() == Model.Wizard.CurrentStep)
{
    @Html.PartialFor(x => x.Wizard.ClientDetails, "_Step");
}
else if (Model.Wizard.Preferences.GetStep() == Model.Wizard.CurrentStep)
{
    @Html.PartialFor(x => x.Wizard.ClientPreferences, "_Step")
}
else if (Model.Wizard.ClientQuestions.GetStep() == Model.Wizard.CurrentStep)
{
    @Html.PartialFor(x => x.Wizard.ClientQuestions, "_Step")
}
```

The wizards have been set up pretty generically except for this part of the view where I choose which partial to display. As you can see from the code above each `if` follows the same structure. The only part that changes is the `Model.Wizard.**Property**` part.

I wanted to try and remove this `if` statement so I don't have to worry about writing an `if` statement for each step I add to a new wizard.

I want to change the code to just something like this:

```
@Html.PartialFor(x => x.ExampleWizardTransaction.GetStepObject(), "_Step");
```

My current attempt for the `GetStepObject` method is as follows:

```
public static T GetStepObject<T>(this IWizardTransaction wizardTransaction) 
     where T : class, new()
{
    var properties = wizardTransaction.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StepAttribute), true).Any());

    PropertyInfo @object = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => ((StepAttribute)Attribute
            .GetCustomAttribute(x.PropertyType, typeof(StepAttribute))).Step == wizardTransaction.CurrentStep);

}
```

The `PropertyInfo @object` part is correctly selecting the property info for the current step in the wizard. I need to be able to return the `PropertyInfo @object` PropertyInfo as its correct type with its current values and return it somehow.

Is this possible?

**EDIT #1:**

Existing `PartialFor` that works in normal scenarios.

```
public static MvcHtmlString PartialFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName)
{
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model;
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
    {
        TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = name }
    };
    return helper.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

The reason the values are not getting binded is that the `var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);` part is returning a blank string. If I hard code the `name` variable to the actual property then the binding works. For example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PartialFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName)
{
    var compiled = expression.Compile();
    var result = compiled.Invoke(helper.ViewData.Model);

    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression); 
    //Should be ExampleWizardTransaction.ClientDetails for this step but is blank

    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
    {
        TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo 
        { 
             //HtmlFieldPrefix = name
             HtmlFieldPrefix = "ExampleWizardTransaction.ClientDetails" 
        }
        //Hard coded this to ExampleWizardTransaction.ClientDetails and the bindings now work
    };

    return helper.Partial(partialViewName, result, viewData);
 }
```

It seems I need to be able to get the name of the wizard object and the current step object as a string value to pass into `TemplateInfo`.

Comment: Can you provide more information as to how are your classes structured? Asking a question about reflection of your classes without knowing how they are structured is somehow difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna take a wild guess at your class structures. Assuming your classes are something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple =false)]
public class StepAttribute: Attribute
{
    public StepEnum Step { get; set; }
}

public interface IWizardStep
{

}

public interface IWizardTransaction
{

}

public enum StepEnum
{
    Previous,
    CurrentStep
}

public class WizardStep: IWizardStep
{
    public string StepName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return StepName;
    }
}

public class Wizard : IWizardTransaction
{
    [Step(Step = StepEnum.Previous)]
    public WizardStep ClientDetails => new WizardStep() { StepName = "ClientDetails" };
    [Step(Step = StepEnum.CurrentStep)]
    public WizardStep ClientQuestions => new WizardStep() { StepName = "ClientQuestions" };
}
```

Assuming also this implementation of **PartialFor** method

```
    public static MvcHtmlString PartialFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName)
    {
        var compiled = expression.Compile();
        var result = compiled.Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
        return html.Partial(partialViewName, result);
    }
```

Then this implementation of **GetStepObject** will work

```
    public static TProperty GetStepObject<TProperty>(this IWizardTransaction wizardTransaction)
        where TProperty : class
    {
        var properties = wizardTransaction.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StepAttribute), true).Any());
        PropertyInfo @object = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => 
                    (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StepAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault()
                                as StepAttribute).Step == StepEnum.CurrentStep);
        return @object.GetValue(wizardTransaction) as TProperty;
    }
```

With this implementation of a partial view named *_Step.cshtml* like this

```
@model PartialView.Models.WizardStep

@Model
```

Your view can call it like this

```
@model PartialView.Models.Wizard
@using PartialView.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Partial view calling";
}

@Html.PartialFor(m=>m.GetStepObject<WizardStep>(), "_Step")
```

And the visual result will be a blank page with the html text **ClientQuestions**

Comment: Hi Alfredo, I've updated my answer to include the code used for an existing PartialFor method. The code you have provided does allow the solution to build and the page to load but it seems that the binding values are lost or not getting bound up.

Comment: Hi Alfredo, I've updated the answer again with the issue causing the binding to be lost.

Comment: I've came up with a work around to get the binding to work so thank you for pointing me in the right direction!